# Can't send http request using python, only sends to https

Tags: python, ssl, post, request

I have the request below:

```
@app.route('/solve', methods=['POST'])
def solve():
if request.method == "POST":
    token = request.form.get('g-recaptcha-response', '')
    print('Posted Token : ' + token)
    Thread(target = tokenremoval, args = [token]).start()
return('Success')
```

I want to send this post request to http://127.0.0.1:5000/solve , but it seems like it is sending to https://127.0.0.1:5000/solve. When I make the post request it sends it to that link above and i get:

This site can’t provide a secure connection

127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.

Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Why can't i send the post request to the http link?

Comment: what seems sending the request to https link? browser?  I don't know much about python web frameworks, but this seems to be server side code. How is it related where are yousending the request to?

Comment: this is flask , right. there must be a place that you are runing the web app like "app.run(host='localhost', port=5000)" . are yo enabling like "app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')"